# DW CS6 - phone gap

Tags: dreamweaver

trying to dip my toe in mobile web apps, my new version of CS6 Dreamweaver seems to be missing phone gap examples.

Create new, from samples has

jQuery Mobile(CDN)

jQuery Mobile (local)

jQueryMobile with Theme (local)

all of the videos on adobes site seem to indicate

jQuery (phonegap)

jQueryMobile with Theme (phonegap)

Do I need these - why are they missing, where can I get them (or other samples)

Answer (score 0):

I found this on a support form... Answers my question but makes me wonder why all the Adobe videos still show these two options when presenters are showing you CS6

```
Carey Burgess (Customer Advocate) 4 months ago
... The jQuery Mobile samples pages under Mobile Starters are the right pages to use to get you started developing for PhoneGap Build in Dreamweaver.

The only reason that CS5.5 had separate listings in there for PhoneGap was to automatically insert the Phonegap JavaScript file (cordova.js), which would be extraneous when building apps with PhoneGap Build.
```

found at:
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/phonegap_templates_in_dreamweaver_cs6